# Back Pay at the Workplace

Tags: feedback

Alright, so in brief this is whats going on. Ive been employeed with my company for 2 1/2years and recently they posted a now hiring ad on indeed. They said the starting rate is 26,000 per year. But, I only make by 25,200. Yesterday 7-9-17 I brought it to my owners attention and he said, I thought I was paying you 2200 a month. I said, no, youve been paying me 25,200 a year. So, this morning 7-10-17 he said, Im giving you a $100 dollar raise per month. But, what should i do about this whole ordeal. I mean, am i entitled to back pay? The pay structure had changed in Feb 2017 to this 26,000 salary (supposedly) but, he didnt tell me in advance.  How do i handle the situation, what should I say, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you *entitled* to back-pay? Most certainly not. The most you can do at this point is ask for a bigger raise or a one-time bonus.

Comment: Have you asked your manager if you are "Enititled" to back pay?  But I will say if you have been there 2.5 years are are still at entry level pay... well they must not value your contributions very much.

Comment: Its a small franchise store that pays in commision and bonuses. But, its only a 5 person team. The Owner and Assistant Manager are husband and wife and the other 3 are salesguys like myself.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I disagree on the duplicate. That question is about someone who had already quit whereas OP is still at the job. Also, the OP's boss agrees that he was underpaid - there is no indication that is the case for the linked question.

Comment: @DavidK - A question is a duplicate if the solution to the question is the same and the circumstances are similar... they do not have to be identical.  In this case not much of a difference that the answers to that question do not apply.  If its not  this its dup of how to approach my boss if i feel underpaid...

Comment: @FrankBorrego See my [first comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/94704/back-pay-at-the-workplace#comment284395_94704). Your employer doesn't have to give you anything. If you aren't happy with just the raise, then see this question: [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid).

Comment: IDrinkAndKnowThings so, what do you suggest?

Comment: "The pay structure had changed in Feb 2017" just *very politely* ask, should you receive "the extra amount since February".

Comment: WAIT A MINUTE - dude, $100 a month is $1200 a year, so that's **26,400** a year now - correct?  THATS GREAT.

Comment: 2200 a month is 26,400 a year...so your making more then the new person ($400 more) a year and $33.33 a month more

Comment: "am i entitled to back pay?" - Nope

Answer (score 6):

You have been happy with the pay to date - So why do you think you should get back pay?

The market has changed. They have to offer more money for new employees.

But to the credit of your manager he has made you an offer. Either accept it or search for a new role.

Comment: The market is changing very much in rural Nebraska. Lol

Comment: It may be - Fewer job applicants on the market? Perhaps they are moving out?

Comment: That can certainly be one of the reasons.